# Creating a tree from a flat list using lodash

Tags: javascript, tree, lodash

I am trying to create a category tree using the array of json objects below.
I want to set a category as a child of another category if its parent equals the id of the other, and I want the posts also to be a children of that category instead of having a separate field for posts, I'll add a flag field that if it is a category or not `isParent`.

It looks like its working alright, but as you may see, if a category has both category and post as child, it'll only show the categories. Another problem with that is if the post has a null value on its array, it will still push them as children.

What are the mistakes in my code, or is there a simpler or better solution to this?

```js
var tree = unflatten(getData());
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
console.log(tree);
pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(tree, null, 4);

document.body.appendChild(pre);

function unflatten(array, parent, tree) {
  tree = typeof tree !== 'undefined' ? tree : [];
  parent = typeof parent !== 'undefined' ? parent : {
    id: 0
  };
  _.map(array, function(arr) {
    _.set(arr, 'isParent', true);
  });
  var children = _.filter(array, function(child) {
    return child.parent == parent.id;
  });

  if (!_.isEmpty(children)) {
    if (parent.id == 0) {
      tree = children;
    } else {
      parent['children'] = children;
    }
    _.each(children, function(child) {
      var posts = _.map(child.posts, function(post) {
        return _.set(post, 'isParent', false);
      });
      child['children'] = posts;
      delete child.posts;
      unflatten(array, child);
    });
  }

  return tree;

}

function getData() {
  return [{
    "id": "c1",
    "parent": "",
    "name": "foo",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p1"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "c2",
    "parent": "1",
    "name": "bar",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p2"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "c3",
    "parent": "",
    "name": "bazz",
    "posts": [
      null
    ]
  }, {
    "id": "c4",
    "parent": "3",
    "name": "sna",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p3"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "c5",
    "parent": "3",
    "name": "ney",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p4"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "c6",
    "parent": "5",
    "name": "tol",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p5"
    }, {
      "id": "p6"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "c7",
    "parent": "5",
    "name": "zap",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p7"
    }, {
      "id": "p8"
    }, {
      "id": "p9"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "c8",
    "parent": "",
    "name": "quz",
    "posts": [
      null
    ]
  }, {
    "id": "c9",
    "parent": "8",
    "name": "meh",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p10"
    }, {
      "id": "p11"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "c10",
    "parent": "8",
    "name": "ror",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p12"
    }, {
      "id": "p13"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "c11",
    "parent": "",
    "name": "gig",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p14"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "c12",
    "name": "xylo",
    "parent": "",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p15"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "c13",
    "parent": "",
    "name": "grr",
    "posts": [{
      "id": "p16"
    }, {
      "id": "p17"
    }, {
      "id": "p14"
    }, {
      "id": "p18"
    }, {
      "id": "p19"
    }, {
      "id": "p20"
    }]
  }]
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Expected Output**

So the expected output will be more like:

```
[
   {
       id: 'c1',
       isParent: true,
       children: [
          {
             id: 'c2',
             isParent: true,
             children: []
          },
          {
             id: 'p1'
             isParent: false
          }
       ]
   }
]
```

And so on..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is very imperative. Try focusing on the "big picture" of data flow instead of writing code by trial-and-error. It's harder, but you get better results (and, in fact, usually it's faster) :)

My idea is to first group the categories by their parents. This is the first line of my solution and it actually becomes much easier after that.

[`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) and [`_.keyBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy) help a lot here:

```
function makeCatTree(data) {
    var groupedByParents = _.groupBy(data, 'parent');
    var catsById = _.keyBy(data, 'id');
    _.each(_.omit(groupedByParents, ''), function(children, parentId) {
        catsById['c' + parentId].children = children; 
    });
    _.each(catsById, function(cat) {
        // isParent will be true when there are subcategories (this is not really a good name, btw.)
        cat.isParent = !_.isEmpty(cat.children); 
        // _.compact below is just for removing null posts
        cat.children = _.compact(_.union(cat.children, cat.posts));
        // optionally, you can also delete cat.posts here.
    });
    return groupedByParents[''];
}
```

I recommend trying each part in the developer console, then it becomes easy to understand.

Comment: In lodash 4 _.indexBy got renamed to [_.keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy)

Comment: Sorry, I've a doubt in ```_.omit(groupedByParents, '')```. Isn't the same to use just ```groupedByParents``` ?

Comment: It removes the group with nodes that have no parent.

Answer (score 4):

I have made a small fidde that I think that is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/tx3uwhke/

```js
var tree = buildTree(getData());
var pre = document.getElementById('a');
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(tree, null, 4);
console.log(jsonString);
pre.innerHTML = jsonString;

document.body.appendChild(pre);

function buildTree(data, parent){
    var result = [];
    parent = typeof parent !== 'undefined' ? parent : {id:""};
    children = _.filter(data, function(value){
        return value.parent === parent.id;
    });
    if(!_.isEmpty(children)){
        _.each(children, function(child){
            if (child != null){
                result.push(child);
                if(!_.isEmpty(child.posts)){
                    var posts = _.filter(child.posts, function(post){
                        return post !== null && typeof post !== 'undefined';
                    });
                    if(!_.isEmpty(posts)){
                        _.forEach(posts, function(post){
                            post.isParent = false;
                        });
                    }
                    result = _.union(result, posts);
                    delete child.posts;
                }
                ownChildren = buildTree(data, child);
                if(!_.isEmpty(ownChildren)){
                    child.isParent = true;
                    child.children = ownChildren;
                }else{
                    child.isParent = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

EDIT: made a new fiddle to contain the `isParent` part you can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tx3uwhke/1/)

Comment: one last bit, where should I add the isParentFlag

Comment: If this reply solved your question, please mark ik as solved.

Comment: yeah, you don't have to rush things, i'm still evaluating if there's a simpler way to do this,

Answer (score 0):

While this problem looks simple, I can remember to have struggled achieving it in a simple way. I therefore created a [generic util to do so](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhAIHUEsBcAtoDtywE4FMMDoCutoAbbWAZ3BGAFgAoW6AWwAcB7NWcAb3ADNCBDWLAxIANOCb92caCzHgA7nHgt84AL680LBuADkhFgBN+peHoDctWhgAerdqgCeTDOAAqmDAElhDADwAYkQYACKC-OKBLIRGGGjhsPwAfOAAvODRsfG+GAHBhGERUTFxCRGpAD6ZIbn5IYkpVnQ0dg4cyMJoPPwAxm5ZZXVBDcWZpfGNqZy04OC9iLGYSABc4ACCaGj8Tv6eWMMFRUkl2eVJycnNcyZJa4OTEdfg0KQAMhj8PGs9hKQYzXU1la9jYHSQXR6-RqhUOowuXFm4Fu-Hu8P4z1eHy+a3QuABtCBLR4uCQvQIcl4EzQdUCfVgbF2R0apzKUwAFEiUfdqSykQsiEZlmtNttdvsfH4RoUWeMzlNUhkANoAXVoAEoeWc4TKxg9zilETQ5phYLg0CgZsa5vNFkKRKIkTdik6Xu9Pt9ePw-hhHdb1IDgSSyRSUDxan46eTGdLjil2dyYXHNUmdXHpkjTebLa6UX6bW7sZ68b6kQHCUHSeTZCgFhhegBrABK9fNpGgADcMHtkuzCK9YCKtjse+JXgAFKQiWAAeU97Mky0HHnEAqWIjW7nV6VSACMWDFPkht1a5r05KQOqRJ0u575-oQeOlwP3L9hSDoMOz2XA8tu0qkE5ThCc4-n4Y5+Oq6qYk+P7XsBs48PeGCPieroINoCjgEgGBYQAolsbDsno6woL+ui9PwSBICwHC7m4-ASAh4AsE+cAPjwejQWWFYtKAICzBAADCmCCAxqBeOAiDxFICxOFoOjgFRSnDvJrEvH45D7ggvAhOQVFGFSZzkAw0C2BgRjYOAACq7ZIAA5hJByRtoDD6qRRhHG8A5uhImA8PEmBGIJlA2KCjjBtWlLoM5eSBK53mXrGsr6hySKvsuoojsyETgNUqUVPmbr6msCYRGiupJHlcpshE-57gehRUUVQG3jwRylYu05arVJy2oKwpJo09XgPuh7NUirXTnO+oAPydQhPWPH1a72qsNXLfwI1jU1SAakOYp7F4aYpbyFQZta55IJe4BKjwZ19eGlX8Cqz6LgQoZ9gOY6kPq26mLdWVMg9KTiEDyUVCqzxZhaTmSnFrnuUgnkhIlsAQ31BUXOyT1xuI93ymMU0ge1IQ-Te03tdS3E0EStD8YJ4AiZ8whKXDUnQDJaByQpugAEwqWKLFsZp4hyG4mBMJg-wQsgjm4+Q7JsC+nxdqQ-3I6g8BuP8V2GQTZSK8rRjQJg0ZoJz6shdQILtLwVahnDtKI9SHleQOGORBtBq9kiuONAd2XoskRUG5tgfA4TFwtfBbUdeAC6Ld7sqrYNOVJNtjVHkVwDACxSCEPJ0BPggry+YxDC4IQBAq12hDs9J2zc-A8k49S8xyEkyBy0ZhvqpNseUyVCddRCS0GqudppyDmfjSgGTsiNvz-PtGyqUdsX1M9rKbZcRpntrjYtr0badl+YcT26FMk39zT8heHAXxKdSkBHQTUideog3vGQX402AMH4Ewb8KIl4f0jPSRkZUM40zPA-XShRn6aTfkcT+FxFQILjAAoBIC6o7kwbSSBaAnDQK2v9cg4NUFSnTikK499rocG9IQJBeRyDKmwBwp+x1RbgA4dgXGLCGCkChsCOYXDN6kH4WwPCfR4DfnEfDBgI1Tw2iujdXGQkp4iGfAI7hrD+FEC6N+VagiRrE0QkcNuZxBHYDzP1WINjQGwNUfAi+miBraN-tSQRkinpGPZCYvRSj8HmJmtSKxZRHFjECZvWxdVnFiO8UE7AqcRDYCYLgMw7I+EaK0fIHJ1J3HrmPM8dQNNMwYDNLDPx8QZxoCYPAKipB2RMJ8TTOmNBIqOxqWgOpDSml7HEAANV7DFRRr816HUEYM8AIzkgpnBtM9wwy94qLUY-AQsAX5vyWSsjBfBBDCCQII0IWBgFjJfs49ZvccjIMmdlcBeQZlzJ0Zsl+Bjq7xG-ORMxv0kmbzAn+ch9zI5DClMs2ZlxnjXKYUUtaOygnPJ-rwTZRyIm3P0YA4B7JuCpJQGU-BeKoLQ0qdmRQyhVCwBxm8nhfDYV5PacCNoYJ7YhhrCiw5IgTlnKReyC5dzFmIohXMhZ69dmQouiaUlsMgb8NcuyBQ3oGyCOyRw-lrDiW8XpmARmQzXhwGVvZFgPcMKqHsvAJShB64IDcDROI5B1I2rhoJG2XSawQEVYQZViKaE7x9qqkgQSJnTN9cnCoqoUwAHERAyQZGgDeijPZ+oVPvKkaAE7XPVboR1Qa0LWjmE4TmsQnZ+GeHMYuCdXj6hVVmqCqaCzXLxc+LNKS8llptIWlCRgPVKpVXwol7aiRzCJB0t1lIq3-MTaGrG8Ys2bh9eiZNFQUxZt8vqNBXsZ2SvADDFAABCFtWIPSBhaMyiKDt2UHKEFyoVKy+VBPnZvJFoqpm3olam3dxVJ11HvZvbcs1bpZvEHwlteLXprCVFmkRtNgTaogB5DSehyDni2BgUgrBkY91JHAVAaGOBjLwAQYg6H6wkHIKFFojA7bcCvUc7lGAmDiCzfFHQaMNC830AAAQYBZKuAgAC0KGMDAHwEQUgwACOicIJYegzAWXcA-OwAAQvJTQPBXL6EMCYMwMmWiwBcG4NGdRnzcGgEYNYSBcAMHomgCwX6zhrB2keOzo9lyWes-EDQzR7W9AtvRYiEpwBSb0OIRe+CVFwGImYVQxbfMs3EmMjjjEMohYTso101yMrbJBf4IzfgMFKldHMXOLE0BlAsi+HyUgLYdm9EVrgLxzPgAAIw-WHiWcQrmLN8Y0EVAspmmt8za9SXEaB8SdaTs13r9WBtrAAMzDYc16H0E2lxrAFuoPrNoSukjYOVwy1XOx1fzTaWb4AAAsi2yg-G9P8Vb3VwAAFZpsnbmGdx7V34ijfG0xNbLWXsFmK3nPITB9PgEAcgWuKEbloBm41tYAA2T7aBvu+l+w9yzVqAeA5K2wfpKAIcoEKHXTBcOzNrAAOzI5uyt9HY9sI9c266aDGX4FjLYSWhGrGBycle5Vy8L8ttzC+gLyC+Cst+GwBOs4QuR4IUnh448+DXNS8MmkdX9i1rpPl-VxOS4FfFJGirsz6QNd4u10uV05STttHrFS9n2BCgOQQOqEgLA8IAEdcDenZHNhJHcGEco4L-VFN7N6nIY7+tD-vrlXpfq8wQ2DsXcBRBoEaoD222-JNSwQ7ynf2Rd27z33vCAi62ZpR3IgC-wH91nqlinYAqZz+X1h4g9Bma4q7hkxefcN6bxL1v+gO+av9O0mmQA)

You only have to write maximum 3 custom callbacks methods.

Here is an example:

```js
import { flattenTreeItemDeep, treeItemFromList } from './tree.util';
import { sortBy } from 'lodash';


    const listItems: Array<ListItem> = [
      // ordered list arrival
      { id: 1, isFolder: true, parent: null },
      { id: 2, isFolder: true, parent: 1 },
      { id: 3, isFolder: false, parent: 2 },
      // unordered arrival
      { id: 4, isFolder: false, parent: 5 },
      { id: 5, isFolder: true, parent: 1 },
      // empty main level folder
      { id: 6, isFolder: true, parent: null },
      // orphan main level file
      { id: 7, isFolder: false, parent: null },
    ];

    const trees = treeItemFromList(
      listItems,
      (listItem) => listItem.isFolder, // return true if the listItem contains items
      (parent, leafChildren) => parent.id === leafChildren.parent, // return true if the leaf children is contained in the parent
      (parent, folderChildren) => parent.id === folderChildren.parent // return true if the children is contained in the parent
    );

console.log(trees);
/*
[
  {
    children: [
      {
        children: [{ data: { id: 3, isFolder: false, parent: 2 }, isLeaf: true }],
        data: { id: 2, isFolder: true, parent: 1 },
        isLeaf: false,
      },
      {
        children: [{ data: { id: 4, isFolder: false, parent: 5 }, isLeaf: true }],
        data: { id: 5, isFolder: true, parent: 1 },
        isLeaf: false,
      },
    ],
    data: { id: 1, isFolder: true, parent: null },
    isLeaf: false,
  },
  { children: [], data: { id: 6, isFolder: true, parent: null }, isLeaf: false },
  {
    data: {
      id: 7,
      isFolder: false,
      parent: null,
    },
    isLeaf: true,
  },
]
*/
```

I did not check with your example as all cases are different, you however need to implement only 3 methods to let the algorithm build the tree for you:

1. If the item is a folder or a leaf (in your case just check if the children contain any non falsy item) i.e. `listItem.posts.some((value)=>!!value)`
2. if a parent contains the leaf child, `(parent, child) => !!parent.posts.filter((val)=>!!val).find(({id})=>child.id === id)`
3. if a parent contains the folder: optional if this is the same logic as for a leaf child.